# Creating symlink for Postgres

Tags: 12.04, symbolic-link, database, postgresql

As a developer, I often ssh right into my local database, just to test my application before pushing my code.

However, I find that every time I want to access Postgres, I have to type in

```
postgres@ubuntu:~$ /usr/local/pgsql/bin/psql test
```

whereas on my work machine, all I have to do is type

```
postgres@ubuntu:~$ psql --dbname=test --username=user
```

I tried creating a symlink, which was successful, but whenever I try connecting to it through this shortcut, I get the following error message:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

How do I get this to work? In case it makes any difference, I'm using a self-compiled version of the 9.1.x series.

**EDIT:** I now know that this isn't really symlinking, but I'm not sure what it's called, or I'm sure I would have found it on Google already. Basically, I want it to run from the shell by typing in `psql [OPTIONS]` like `rvm [OPTIONS]` or `ruby [OPTIONS]`.

I know there's a package named `postgresql-client-common` & a bunch of other Postgres packages through `apt-get`, but I would prefer not using the `apt-get` version so I can update Postgres on the fly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's just a matter of calling on psql directly you need to make sure the path "/usr/local/pgsql/bin" is included in $PATH when you are logging in.   Oftentimes this has to do with setting the PATH variable appropriately in in /etc/profile (or ~/.profile) or if you are using bash, then this would be /etc/bashrc or ~/.bashrc.

e.g.

export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/psql/bin"

Additionally.. the psql command expects the args as follow;  psql <dbname> <username> (you can use --flags to specify the same).

If you supply "psql test"- then it will assume the username of the current user (as seen by whoami command).

Hope  this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use the Linux Alias?

```
alias psql=/usr/local/pgsql/bin/psql
```

To make a permanent alias, just put this line in

```
~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile
```

Answer (score 0):

What about the convenience of a function?

```
postgres@ubuntu:~$ function psqltest {
> /usr/local/pgsql/bin/psql test
> }
postgres@ubuntu:~$
```

Once defined, this will run  /usr/local/pgsql/bin/psql test in your bash shell whenever you type

```
postgres@ubuntu:~$ psqltest
```

One last tip: Store the functions that you want to retain and use again in the $HOME/.bashrc  file.

If you are interested in writing bash functions, I've found a tutorial https://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/bash-functions.php